# Thymeleaf th: utext - Put text outside the tag

Tags: thymeleaf

I'm new in thymeleaf and I try to create a template. My problem is this code:

```
<p th:utext="${story.info}" >
</p>
```

I want to get this output:

```
<p> <h1> Text</h1> ... </p>
```

But this is the real output:

```
<p> </p><h1> Text</h1> ...
```

I have to do to adjust the text to the right position

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't do that normally.  Your html is malformed somewhere (and you didn't post enough of it to be able to debug this).

Comment: You should try to replace your <p> by a <div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options to achieve this. first, you might want to use th:remove tag along with th:utext.

> In thymeleaf, **th:remov**e can behave in five different ways, depending
>   on its value:
>
> **all:** Remove both the containing tag and all its children.
>
> **body:** Do notremove the containing tag, but remove all its children.
>
> **tag:** Remove the containing tag, but do not remove its children.
>
> **all-but-first:** Remove all children of the containing tag except the first one.
>
> **none :** Do nothing. This value is useful for dynamic evaluation.

Second, send the html escaped string from the backend. This approach may need some extra processing though. Thnx

Controller class

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import java.util.Locale;


@Controller
public class NavigationController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NavigationController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @GetMapping({"/", "/index"})
    public String defaultPage(final Model model, final Locale locale){
        model.addAttribute("headertext", "<h1> Text</h1>");
        return "index";
    }

}
```

Index.jsp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
        xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>th:utext</title>

</head>
<body>
<span th:text="${headertext}"/>
<p th:utext="${headertext}"></p>
<p th:utext="${'th:remove=all'+headertext}" th:remove="all"></p>
<p th:utext="${'th:remove=body'+headertext}" th:remove="body"></p>
<p th:utext="${'th:remove=tag'+headertext}" th:remove="tag"></p>
<p th:utext="${'th:remove=all-but-first'+headertext}" th:remove="all-but-first"></p>
<p th:utext="${'th:remove=none'+headertext}" th:remove="none"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: index.jsp page output]

Comment: See if it can help you. Or you should  elaborate the use case and put backend code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<div class="outside-tag">
  <th:block th:utext="${unescapedText}"></th:block>
</div>
```

I tried it with p tag, but it didn't work.
div tag works fine